# REFrostedViewController set selection of menu items

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to set selection of table view cells with some background color while switching between different menu items.

I am using REFrostedViewController library.

Here's my code for the Menu Controller of `REFrostedViewController` :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.opaque = NO;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.tableView sizeToFit];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NavigationVC *navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentController"];

            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0: {
                    // Push view controller 1
                }
                    break;

                case 1: {
                    // Push view controller 2
                }

                    break;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify `setSelected:animated:` method of `UITableViewCell` like this

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    UIView * selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [selectedBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[Utility greenColor]]; // set color here
    [self setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundView];
}
```

Then call this method from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate or implement it on `willDisplayCell`.